# Shell: How to use screen and wait for a couple of background processes in a shell script

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, wait, gnu-screen

I am writing a shell script for a couple of long running processes. 
First of all I need to run all commands in the screen session manager, so that the execution of a process does not end if a user has been disconnected. 
Later I need wait for some background processes, which has been created before, to end, so that the following process can start.

My question is how to start a screen session in a shell script and wait for the background processes to end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't invoke `screen` (or `nohup`) on the running process, you have to do `screen script`.  You could however do what nohup does, trap SIGHUP and redirect output to a file.

```
exec > OUT 2>&1
trap '' 1
```

To wait for background processes, save the pid when you create it and then call wait

```
foo&
PID1=$!
bar&
PID2=$1
wait $PID1 $PID2
```

Or alternatively just wait for everything to finish.

```
foo&
bar&
wait
```

Comment: what worked out well. i collected the PIDs during a for loop in a string variable. The error was that there was no space character between the PIDs ... my fault :D

Answer (score 5):

A google search for "scripting screen" gives [this](http://blog.lathi.net/articles/2008/09/13/scripting-screen) as the first result. It looks like you can create named screen sessions with `screen -d -m -S nameOfSession`. Then `screen -X -S <session name> screen` will create a window in the screen session 'nameOfSession.' You can communicate with this window 1 (i.e. give commands for this screen session window 1 to run) by using

```
screen -X -S test -p 1 stuff "your command here ^M"
```

The "your_command_here" is the command you want to run. The `^M` is the carriage return control character (you type Ctrl-V then Enter/Return in a terminal). The ^M will essentially "press return/enter" so that the command is run in this screen session. Play around with it.

Since you want to wait for your commands to finish, I would suggest forking the processes, via the ampersand:

`your_command &`
Immediately after, the process-id of the forked of process is in $!. You can wait for all background processes to finish running by running `wait`.

I would suggest the [screen reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/).