# How to wait until everything started by a shell script ends?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using nested shell scripts.

My question is a bit similar to the ones asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566304/shell-script-not-waiting) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405039/shell-how-to-use-screen-and-wait-for-a-couple-of-background-processes-in-a-shel). But not exactly the same.

I have tried to get the solution from these but unsuccessful.

In my **OuterMostShellScript.sh**, I do something like this:

```
some commands
./runThisScriptX.sh
other commands
end of script.
```

**runThisScriptX.sh** contains a loop running some processes in the background by using `&` operator.

I want each process started by the `./runThisScriptX.sh` command finish before the control moves to the, which i say `other commands` line in the above code.

how to achieve this?

EDIT: I also did like this:

```
some commands
./runThisScriptX.sh
wait
other commands
end of script.
```

but it did not work.

Comment: remove the `&` from the script?

Comment: No I can not. I want them take the advantage of parallel/multicore. Which they already are taking...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish and return exit code !=0 when any subprocess ends with code !=0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I have used `wait` but did not work

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I have added some edit part in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `runThisScriptX.sh`, you should wait for the parallel children to complete before exiting:

```
child1 &
child2 &
child3 &
wait
```

Then in `OuterMostShellScript.sh`, you run `runThisScriptX.sh` itself in the background, and wait for it.

```
some commands
./runThisScriptX.sh &
wait
other commands
end of script.
```

`wait` can only be used to wait on processes started by the current shell.

Comment: Works fine. if i do not run `./runThisScriptX.sh` itself in the background, then only the wait inside this script will be enough, right?

Comment: Correct. The `wait` prevents `runThisScriptX.sh` from continuing (and thus exiting) until the child processes complete.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

- Source your script
- Use `wait`

Your script would not look like:

```
some commands
. ./runThisScriptX.sh          # Note the leading . followed by space
wait                           # This would wait for the sourced script to finish
other commands
end of script
```

Comment: note: the sourced script could potentially overwrite your environment variables. be careful ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath You're right, but `wait` is useless without sourcing.

Comment: that's why it's a "note". based on the comments of the OP I would put that `wait` in the other script.

Comment: I have added some edit part in the question... let me check what you have suggested.

Comment: Alternatively you can run a sourced script in a sub-shell by enclosing in parens. `(. ./runThisScriptX.sh; wait)` will also work and all variables preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`wait`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Builtins) built-in command:

```
wait
```

This waits for all background processes started directly by the shell to complete before continuing.

Comment: If the script is started with `./` and without `&`, there's nothing that can be done until the sub-script finishes.  No command can do anything unless the sub-processes are run in the background.  The command run via `./` can do the waiting; or as has been discussed, the script will have to be sourced.  If there's still an issue with variables, maybe the answer is `( . ./Whatever; wait)`.  But the fundamental answer remains `wait` — the only residual issue is deciding where to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the bash built-in `wait`; from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) -

> Wait for each specified process and return its termination status. Each n may be a 
>   process ID or a job specification; if a job spec is given, all processes in that job's 
>   pipeline are waited for. If n is not given, all currently active child processes are waited 
>   for, and the return status is zero. If n specifies a non-existent process or job, the 
>   return status is 127. Otherwise, the return status is the exit status of the last process 
>   or job waited for.

Or, don't background the tasks.